# Up Close and Deadly and Full-Attack Actions

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, firearms, gunslinger

Do you need to spend 1 grit point for each attack made as part of a full-attack action when using the [Pistolero](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/gunslinger/archetypes/paizo-gunslinger-archetypes/pistolero/) Deed up Close and Deadly?

The Deed says:

> **Up Close and Deadly (Ex)**: At 1st level, **when the pistolero hits a target with a one-handed firearm that is not making a scatter shot**, she can spend 1 grit point to deal 1d6 points of extra damage on a hit. If she misses with the attack, she grazes the target, dealing half the extra damage anyway. This is precision damage and is not multiplied if the attack is a critical hit. This precision damage increases to 2d6 at 5th level, to 3d6 at 10th level, to 4d6 at 15th level, and to 5d6 at 20th level. This precision damage stacks with sneak attack and other forms of precision damage.

Emphasis mine.  The wording of the deed seems to indicate that you need to do this for each attack, but that seems a little unfair - a single full-attack would require you to empty your grit pool if you have low wisdom.  Would the extra precision damage apply to each attack made as part of the action, or only the first attack, if I spent one grit point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As written, you’re right: extra damage only to that attack. Spend more Grit to apply it to more attacks.

Now, *Pathfinder* firearms are extremely weak, and the gunslinger class only partially remedies their many failings. You could make a very good case that a bit more damage isn’t unreasonable, particularly considering just how precious Grit is. I would recommend talking to your DM about it; may he’ll houserule it. But unless he does, it’s just the one attack.

Answer (score 1):

The text is quite clear that it is one grit per attack and that is how we play it.

Strange we found Gunslinger if anything over powered (DM might have made a mistake in allowing modern weapons) and pistolero especially so and I would not give them any more damage. May be a way off but Signature Deed with Up Close and Personal is quite good.

Comment: I've heard repeatedly that gunslingers are balanced for emerging weapons, where advanced firearms are reserved as high-level rewards rather than common weapons.

Answer (score 0):

Path firearms are not weak as long as they're at least commonplace enough that you don't need to dump feats to get them and you can use gunslinger's dex bonus to damage, or do some other shenanigans like the adding the "guided" quality with a WIS based build.

Check this out: firearms hit touch ac instead of normal ac within first range increment. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E2-s8weiulPoBQjdI05LBzOUToyoZIdSsLKxHAvf8F8/edit#gid=3
Look at this difference between normal AC progression for enemies vs. touch. Generally most enemies have sub-20 touch AC and bosses sub-30 up until very very late stages of the game. This allows you to easily combine deadly aim and two-weapon fighting + rapid shot ***without*** sacrificing your ability to hit consistently with shots later in the combo. Once BAB hits 11 (Gunslingers have full BAB), you have 3 attacks with main hand pistol + 3 attacks with off-hand pistol + 2 more with each hand while rapid shooting for ***8 attacks*** that will still ***reliably*** hit most enemies, even if you deadly aim for -3/+6.

Monks and two-weapon users often *have* extra attacks but at a +3 for the 6th attack are never going to hit with them unless the enemies are severely debuffed. Two-weapon gunslingers can hit almost always. At CR 20 the median touch AC is 13 and regular AC is 37. A gunslinger's 6th attack needs to have +8 to hit pretty consistently, while a monk needs +32 (or +18 to even have a chance to hit outside of a critical).

Deeds can be pretty good but a lot of them are useless. And unlike ki you get to replenish your pool pretty frequently, so whenever you secure a kill you get back the grit, meaning you get this once per enemy for free. Plus another grit for each crit along the way.

So for my onion here, being able to unload your grit for the day into an enemy for a couple of d6's per grit point, and then get at least one of those refunded from the kill, is pretty sweet as is. I don't think this is a deed to make a build around, but it's one of the better ones just for letting you add a substantial amount of damage.

Adding half-scaled rogue sneak attack damage with zero conditions to prop for 1 grit *** per turn*** seems pretty busted, especially because that grit would get refunded every time you got a kill (which you would be getting every turn).